# probability question of a set of features

Tags: probability

suppose we have set of events as follow:
$$\{\emptyset, a, b, c, d, ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd, abc, abd, acd, bcd, abcd\}$$ whereas a b c and d are four different features that might be observed solely or coupled with each others as per in the set above.
how can we calculate the probability of

1- $P(a)$ ?

2- $P(ab)$ ?

3- $P(a\mid b)$ ?

Comment: You cannot calculate the probability of $P(a)$ yet. you need to say something more about the events. Are they equiprobable?

Comment: yes they are. each event has a probability weight (1/16)

Comment: is $a$ an event? $ab$ an event? Maybe you only need to calculate $P(a \mid b)$.

Comment: Maybe you stated a different  problem then the one you wanted to solve

Comment: well, i think i forget to mention that {a} is a subset of {ab}

Comment: and when i ask for the probability of a . the answer will be 8 /16 which is all events that contain a over the problem space

Comment: Yes, @ana, that was my first thought too about *this presentation* of the problem. However, see Conrado Costa's answer. Observe that, as events, you listed *all* subsets of $\{a,b,c,d\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is in 8 of your 16 events. $ab$ is in 4 of your 16 events. There are 8 events with $b$ in them, 4 of which have $a$ in them.

Thus 1/2, 1/4, 1/2 are the answers you are looking for.

Edit: The $\varnothing$ just means neither $a, b, c,$ or $d$ happened (you can think of abcd as all 4 events happened, etc.).

Comment: What do you think about the event $\emptyset$ with probability $1/16$?

Comment: @ConradoCosta The null symbol is being used to indicate an empty *list of features*, rather than a non-event.

Comment: sorry i had to disconnect to catch my flight, anyways thank you all. i think mark get me right. i knew the answer already would be like this but i found it really hard to represent it mathematically. like if i know there’re set of features aggregate in a function in such a systematic way. while it would be hard to right the set of problem space manually if four example we had 8 features a.b,c…etc and to capture all combination is a hectic work and not easy to find the probability of any feature among the space 
is there any way to represent this notion as per binomial or anything such like

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean $\Omega = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is the set of subsets of $\Omega$. Moreover, you assign to each atom ($\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{d\}$) an equal probability of $1/4$.

In this context

1) $P(\{a\}) =\frac{1}{4}$

2) $P(\{a,b\}) = \frac{2}{4}$

3) $$P(\{a\}\mid \{b\}) = \frac{P(\{a\} \cap \{b\})}{P(\{b\})} = \frac{P(\emptyset)}{1/4} = 0$$

Comment: Note that $P(A|B)=\displaystyle\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ supposed $P(B)>0$.

Comment: i don’t think if you get my question correctly.
imagine if we have a set of 4 features  a, b , c and d  and they all aggregate in another function in which this function could be any event of the first set i show above ( any possible combination
giving that the function is exist what is the probability that the feature  (a) is within the selection

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question. but $\emptyset$ is an event? I don't imagine this event as having probability $1/16$. That would be very unusual. Please clarify this point to me

Comment: @ConradoCosta It is event that none of the four features occur in an outcome.  Like: if we toss four coins of different denominations, it is the event that none of them reveal heads; which occurs with probability $1/16$.

Comment: Note: $\mathsf P(\varnothing)$ is a different concept than $\mathsf P(\omega=\emptyset)$.  The former: the probability that no outcome happens.  The latter: the probability that the outcome contains nothing.  (An empty outcome is still something.)

Comment: Maybe, in this case @Mark is right...

Comment: sorry i had to disconnect to catch my flight, anyways thank you all. i think mark get me right. i knew the answer already would be like this but i found it really hard to represent it mathematically. like if i know there’re set of features aggregate in a function in such a systematic way. while it would be hard to right the set of problem space manually if four example we had 8 features a.b,c…etc and to capture all combination is a hectic work and not easy to find the probability of any feature among the space 
is there any way to represent this notion as per binomial or anything such like

Answer (score 0):

You have a set of 16 *equiprobable* outcomes: $$\Big\{∅,\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{d\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{a,d\},\{b,c\},\{b,d\},\{c,d\},\{a,b,c\},\{a,b,d\},\{a,c,d\},\{b,c,d\},\{a,b,c,d\}\Big\}$$

Let $\omega$ be an outcome.

There are 8 of 16 outcomes with feature $a$, so: $\mathsf P(a\in\omega) = \frac 8{16} = \frac 1 2$

Similarly $\mathsf P(\{a,b\}\subseteq\omega) = \frac 4 {16} = \frac 1 4$

Now, of the 8 outcomes that feature $b$, 4 of them feature $a$, so $\mathsf P(a\in\omega\mid b\in\omega) = \frac{4}{8} = \frac 1 2$.

And so on.

---

What we are observing is that each feature has a probability of $1/2$ of occurring in an outcome, *independently* of the other features.

Comment: why did you change my answer? you edited it in a manner I don't recognise any of what is written,  is it possible to revert it to the original one?

Comment: Yes. @ConradoCosta .  If dissatisfied with an edit you can click the "edited..." link and then use the Rollback button on the appropriate past edit to revert to the original.  (I've just done that for you)